# How To Choose Between Two (Similar) Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-third-generation

I'm playing Pokemon Emerald, although this is generic to any pokemon game. My questions are really about two ways of picking Pokemon: **How do I pick Pokemon, at all?** I assume I should have some sort of strategy around ability types (eg. fire, electric) and weaknesses, and some sort of balance. How do I go about designing a basic party?

Given that I have already decided on, say, a psychic or stone Pokemon, my next question is: **how do I pick between two similar-type Pokemon?**

Let's say I have Ralts (psychic type), and now capture an Abra (psychic type). Both have different stats, moves, and evolutions; how do I decide which one to pick over the other? Do I look at moves? Weaknesses? Final evolutions?

Comment: Your question could be split in two separate question, for better understand and a better quality on the answers as well

Comment: Yes, I know. I already have a general answer for the first (see my other questions), so my focus is more the second question

Answer (score 2):

As for types, I have found this for Diamond and Pearl, so I don't know how much this has changed. Here is a list of pokemon types with few weaknesses (it does rely on some pokemon having the right abilities).

## No Weaknesses

1.Dark & Ghost - Still Vulnerable to the move Foresight and Scrappy ability.

2.Electric with Levitate

3.Dark & Poison with Levitate

4.Bug & Steel with Flash Fire

## One Weakness

1.Electric (Ground)

2.Water & Dragon (Dragon)

3.Dark & Poison (Ground)

4.Normal (Fighting)

5.Normal & Ghost (Dark)

6.Bug & Steel (Fire)

7.Water & Ground (Grass)

As for choosing between similar type pokemon, players have different strategies when they do this. Some people choose pokemon with the best moves [which is a very relative term between players], others choose by type, or choose based on stat growth.

Then it depends what events you want to use your pokemon in. Because newer pokemon games have contests, special battle arenas, effort values to grow specific stats, and breeding, you may want to consider different types of strategies.

Comment: Ironically, the best game that taught me pokemon strategies was Pokemon Stadium 2 because it had the learning center to teach you how to use types and special abilities introduced in the gold, silver, & crystal editions. I wish their was something like that for the newer games.

Comment: I also realized another common way to get around pokemon with weaknesses. The move Skill Swap can remove the protective skill [Flash Fire and Levitate] and make them vulnerable to the type. There are also abilities and attacks that can change this skill to get rid of it. It is one of those abilities that isn't used often, but can really mess with a trainer who has never seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for Emerald specifically, but when forming a team you want to essentially cover as many types as possible with as few weaknesses as possible. Look up charts to compare what type is good against what, combine that with looking up specific Pokemon in the types you decide to choose, and look at what moves they learn and what TMs you can teach them. Then try to cover the types you missed in a good combination with some of your chosen Pokemon.

As far as specific Pokemon within the same type go, you want to look at their stats pretty closely, and pair that up with your general playing style (straight out attack? status change them into submission then go for the kill? exhaust their moves with heals and high-hp? etc).

For Ralts vs Abra, look at their moves, what combinations of moves you can give them, their general stats, and whether you can easily get their final form (i.e. can you trade your kadabra, etc). Final evolution means nothing except for stats, since appearance won't win you battles, and remember to always remember each Pokemon's strengths and weaknesses. Have your belt remembered well enough that you can look at an enemy's Pokemon and instantly know which of yours will fight it most effectively.

Of course you can just get a fast, high-attack Pokemon and outlevel it so you can solo anyone you fight, but that takes the fun out of the game, right?

Comment: As to your last comment ... that's what makes it *oh so much fun* in subsequent play-throughts, when you just rock it :)

Answer (score 1):

How is weaknesses even a question when you are choosing between two same-type pokemon. XD

1) Look at their Smogon tier here: http://www.smogon.com/dex/rs/pokemon

2) Check out the evolutions. Doing so for the example reveals ralts is much better than abra because it evolves into Gardevoir.

3) Look at their moveset on smogon or bulbapedia. I wont say the moveset matters much because any pokemon has at least one good moveset it can utilize.

Answer (score 1):

Check the final evolutions (because this is what ultimately matters), then the respective Pokemon's abilities, movepool, and stats.

We'll use Ralts vs. Abra as an example. This is effectively Gardevoir vs. Alakazam, since those are the final evolved forms. Look at their Smogon analysis pages. Here is the one for [Gardevoir](https://www.smogon.com/dex/rs/pokemon/gardevoir/) and here is the one for [Alakazam](https://www.smogon.com/dex/rs/pokemon/alakazam/) (for Ruby/Sapphire/Emerald).

We can immediately note some differences:

- They both have a very strong Special Attack state, but Alakazam is slightly stronger.
- More importantly, Alakazam is *fast*. It has base 120 Speed, which puts it well above most Pokemon. Gardevoir's 80 speed is pathetic in comparison, and not enough for sweeping* without boosts.
- Both Alakazam and Gardevoir are relatively fragile, but Alakazam is significantly more fragile since it HP and defensive stats are lower. Gardevoir's 115 Special Defense is very respectable, so it can sponge Special hits.
- Alakazam gets Synchronize & Inner Focus as its abilities, while Gardevoir gets Synchronize & Trace. In other words, Gardevoir's abilities are more useful. Inner Focus is effectively a null ability, while Synchronize is relatively weak as well. Trace is not outstanding, but it's more useful: you can e.g. Trace Levitate for an extra immunity.

And then you can look through their movepools. They share most moves, but there are some noticeable differences. Here it's important to be familiar with the "meta" and know which moves are worth using. I don't know R/S well, but based on my experience with other generations, these moves are notable (the analysis pages agree, since these moves get used in the movesets available):

- Alakazam gets Encore and Recover. Encore is a niche move that helps your team set up, while Recover gives Alakazam longevity.
- Gardevoir gets Will-O-Wisp, Wish, Memento, and Hypnosis. Will-O-Wisp means it can act as a check to slower physical attackers. Wish and Memento are strong support moves. Hypnosis is less strong, but it's still a sleep-inducing move that you can use to set up.

These differences therefore lead to the ultimate answer to your question:

- Alakazam is a fast offensive attacker. You will usually give him offensive EVs (i.e. in Special Attack and Speed). He will hit hard, but he will usually not be able to take much damage. Like a firefly, he will burn brightly, but only for a short while.
- Gardevoir is more of a support Pokemon. You use her to make your other Pokemon shine. She will be more defensive, with EVs in defensive stats. She will be usually able to take a hit. However, offensively she is likely to be lacking not just because you won't have the space for support moves on sweepers, but also because you will not be investing in Special Attack or Speed.

Ultimately which Pokemon you use will depend on what role you need it to fulfil in your team.

**Pedantic sidenote**: both Alakazam and Gardevoir are rated in the UUBL tier for R/S at Smogon. If they are not in the same tier, then a heuristic is that the Pokemon that is in the higher tier is the "better" Pokemon - but it is only a heuristic; it is possible the lower-tier Pokemon is more appropriate for your team.

*A *sweeper* is a Pokemon whose purpose is to hit hard and knock out the other team's Pokemon. It is distinct from walls and supports (who do things like set up entry hazards and absorb hits).